# Why swap space doesn't get filesystem check at boot time?

Tags: fstab, swap, fsck

As I was checking the /etc/fstab I noticed that the swap space has attr pass=0, which means its filesystem is not checked at boot time.
Can anyone please tell me why is this behavior for?

Comment: There is no (filesystem) structure in a Swap file. Consequently there is no fsck. mkswp does not format a swap partition or file, it just writes a signature to make sure the kernel does not incidentally swapon any area which has useful data.

Comment: @eckes Your comment looks very much like an answer (and pretty similar to the accepted one). Please [don't post answers as comments](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5345/251216).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At boot time, swap doesn’t contain any data which would need to be recovered, so there’s no point in writing a tool to repair swap. If a swap partition or file is corrupted in such a way that `swapon` can’t make use of it, the fix is to `mkswap` it again — there’s no need for a separate `fsck.swap` tool, so there isn’t one and `/etc/fstab` isn’t set up to use one.

It might then seem nice for `swapon` to automatically `mkswap` if necessary, but that would mean that any mistake in the arguments to `swapon` would be instantly fatal to the data stored in the given volume or file.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Swap is a dump. Everything within it is *disposable*. It's like a "scratch" file. Just a place to temporarily put things in, and later overwrite them without cause for worry. Technically it's only used when there's memory pressure (lots of *active* things in RAM).

Hope that helps clarify things a bit. :)